# maximize $\csc{(\pi b)}\sin{(\pi ab)}+\csc{(\pi (\frac{1}{a}-b))}\sin{(\pi a(\frac{1}{a}-b))}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Let $x\in [0, \frac{1}{a}]$ for a positive integer $a$.

$f(x)=\csc{(\pi x)}\sin{(\pi ax)}=\frac{\sin{(\pi ax)}}{\sin{(\pi x)}}$.

[image]

When $b\in[0, \frac{1}{2a}]$, I want to prove that $b$ maximizing

$f(b)+f(\frac{1}{a}-b)$

is $b=\frac{1}{2a}$.

Remark: If $f(x)$ is concave on $[0, \frac{1}{a}]$, the statement is trivially true. But generally, $f(x)$ is not concave unless $a=2$. (almost concave though)

Comment: it is not true that $b=\dfrac{1}{2a}$ you will get max. the max is when $b<\dfrac{1}{2a}$.for $a=2，b=0.2$ to get max.